# How to close all opened instances of the Terminal at once in PyCharm

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, ide, window

In Pycharm, I have multiple Terminal processes opened. How can I close all of them at once without having to close each one of them manually?

- PyCharm version 2020.1.2
- Windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the terminal tabs may be closed by right-clicking one of the tabs, and then selecting `Close All`.

[image]